# Caching Webapp interface and restoring it using html5 localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

Okay. So i have heard plenty about building apps using phonegap and html5. the app works fine but it access a web service to populate the div for display. The service runs well what i want to implement is a caching mechanism for storing the last interface from the service using local-storage while a fresh request is going on in the background.

This is my javascript code. Please what am i doing wrong.

P.S am a html5/js intermediate user. However, i user php really well.

```
function loadHome()
{

$("#post_display").html(waitText); 
$.get(api_url',{ app_key: my_app_key } ,
function(data){
    if(('localStorage' in window) && window['localStorage'] !== null)
    {
        localStorage.setItem('data_home',data); alert(localStorage.getItem(data_home));
    }
    $("#post_display").html(data) }
    );

}
```

so far, the alert works and shows me the data stored. Now how do i display the data when the user returns to the page. what conditional logic do i use?
sample

```
if(localstorage.data_home){ //display store data here } 
else{//run the ajax call to the api service}
```

i dont know how to go about this. Help.

Answer (score 0):

just check before you call ajax. It's just a sample, you need to refact your source code.

```js
function loadHome()
{

$("#post_display").html(waitText); 
if(('localStorage' in window) && window['localStorage'] !== null && localStorage.getItem('data_home')){
    $("#post_display").html(localStorage.getItem('data_home'));
    return;
}
$.get(api_url',{ app_key: my_app_key } ,
function(data){
    if(('localStorage' in window) && window['localStorage'] !== null)
    {
        localStorage.setItem('data_home',data); alert(localStorage.getItem(data_home));
    }
    $("#post_display").html(data) }
    );

}
```

Comment: Just tried this code sample...it does not work. it displays the loading text but not the stored data